# I keep getting NaN for a value that is produced from all integers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery based math program that will display and average my quiz scores. Everything works perfectly except that in my for loop I have:

```
specQuizTotalValue += total;
```

for a var "specQuizTotalValue" that is globally set to 0.

For some reason I keep getting NaN for specQuizTotalValue, even though typeof in each iteration as well as the global definition comes back "number". I also tried pushing to an Array and with two iterations I got [NaN, 16, 36] (16 and 36 are the correct values).

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mjhd/jf39f/

```
var specQuizUL = $('#specQuiz ul').length;

var specQuizTotalValue = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= specQuizUL; i++){
var preval = $('#specQuiz ul:nth-child(' + i + ') li:nth-child(2)').html();
var value = parseInt(preval);

var pretot = $('#specQuiz ul:nth-child(' + i + ') li:nth-child(3)').html();
var total = parseInt(pretot);

var avg = (value/total).toFixed(2) * 100;
$('#specQuiz ul:nth-child(' + i + ')').append('<li>' + avg + ' %</li>');

    specQuizTotalValue += total; 
}

 $('#specQuizTotal').append('<h3>' + specQuizTotalValue + '</h3>');
```

Please help!!

Comment: FYI, `NaN` **is** a number value, despite its name.

Comment: Start the loop at `1`.

Comment: I actually started at 1 then subtracted 1 later - still NaN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `:nth-child` selector is **1**-based](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), not 0-based. In the first iteration,

```
$('#specQuiz ul:nth-child(0) li:nth-child(2)')
```

will result in an empty jQuery object, so `.html()` will return `undefined`, and `parseInt(undefined)` returns `NaN`.

Change your `for` loop to start from 1:

```
for(i = 1; i <= specQuizUL; i++) {
```

Comment: This didn't completely answer my question but I was able to find the answer using the info! The nth-child selector was used intentionally and was selecting the correct li elements, however for the ul I had to switch to eq() - combined with starting my loop at 1 Voila! Thanks guys!!  - fiddle was updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjhd/jf39f/2/ if anyone else is reading this for help with a similar problem!

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem:

```
var pretot = $('#specQuiz ul:nth-child(' + i + ') li:nth-child(3)').html();
    console.log(i,pretot,parseInt(pretot));
var total = parseInt(pretot);
```

when `i` is 0, `pretot` is `undefined`, since that particular selector is not selecting anything. so when `pretot` is undefined, `parseInt(pretot)` evaluates to `NaN`, and one `NaN` value in a cumulative total will ruin the entire total.